In the Rest API I developed with Java Spring, where I authenticate with Firebase Auth, I get an access error even though the token is correct
In the Rest API I developed with Java Spring, where I authenticate with Firebase Auth, I receive a response from this mailman even though the token is correct.
{
"timestamp": "2024-05-22T22:40:11.899+00:00",
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Access Denied",
"path": "/api/1.0/users"
}
In Println outputs, the verifyTokrn function in the FirebaseTokenVerifier class gives the "verify" output.
public class FirebaseTokenVerifier {
    private final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    public FirebaseTokenVerifier() {
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    public FirebaseToken verifyToken(String token) {
        try {
            FirebaseToken decodedToken = firebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(token);
            System.err.println("Verify");
            return decodedToken;
        } catch (FirebaseAuthException e) {
            System.err.println("No Verify");
            return null;
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeFirebaseApp() {
        try {
            FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("./serviceAccountKey.json");
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error initializing Firebase App", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public FirebaseTokenVerifier firebaseTokenVerifier() {
        return new FirebaseTokenVerifier();
    }

    @Bean
    public FirebaseTokenAuthenticationFilter firebaseTokenAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        FirebaseTokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new FirebaseTokenAuthenticationFilter(firebaseTokenVerifier());
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        FirebaseTokenAuthenticationFilter filter = firebaseTokenAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class));

        http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); // FirebaseTokenAuthenticationFilter'ı UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'dan önce ekle
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/1.0/users/**")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        List<UserDetails> users = new ArrayList<>();
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        users.add(user);
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(authenticationProvider()));
    }
}

public class FirebaseTokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private final FirebaseTokenVerifier firebaseTokenVerifier;

    public FirebaseTokenAuthenticationFilter(FirebaseTokenVerifier firebaseTokenVerifier) {
        super(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"));
        this.firebaseTokenVerifier = firebaseTokenVerifier;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    private Authentication getAuthentication(String jwtToken) {
        FirebaseToken token = firebaseTokenVerifier.verifyToken(jwtToken);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authoritiesList = new ArrayList<>();
        authoritiesList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getUid(), token, authoritiesList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (token != null && token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            token = token.substring(7); // "Bearer " ifadesini kaldır
            if (firebaseTokenVerifier.verifyToken(token) != null) {
                return getAuthentication(token);
            }
        }

        // Token doğrulanamadı veya eksik
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Invalid or missing token");
        return null;
    }
}

public class FirebaseTokenAuthentication extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {
    private final String token;

    public FirebaseTokenAuthentication(String token) {
        super(Collections.emptyList());
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return token;
    }
}



The token is being verified but I think there was an authorization error during authentication. I couldn't find the problem.
